# androidTheme in cordova-plugin-datepicker plugin is not working properly

Tags: android

I have added cordova-plugin-datepicker plugin to my project. It is working fine in older android version. But in android 7.1, it is not showing selected date.
Any Help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT` in `androidTheme`

```
var options = {
            date: curDt,
            mode: 'date',
            androidTheme : datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is something like

```
var options = {
            date: curDt,
            mode: 'date',
            androidTheme : 3
        };
```